# Link html pages to other html pages on chromebook

Tags: html, css, chromebook

I wanted to make a website that would help people study better. It's still pretty basic since I don't actually know enough JavaScript to make it cool. I wanted to link one page to another through buttons, but I have no luck in doing so. I use a Chromebook and I had seen that the same link you'd use on a computer using windows isn't the same.
Here is what I did, but nothing seems to work. It is saved in the folder, Websites and it's named About.html

HTML code

```
<ul>
  <li><a href="Websites/About.html">Home|</a></li>
  <li><a href="">About|</a></li>
  <li><a href="">Schools|</a></li>
  <li><a href="">Submit Notes|</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: I mean your links ahve no adress to link to added

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your index.html page (start page) is located in the same folder as your About.html file. If it is, your code would be a follows:

```
<ul>
    <li><a href="About.html">Home|</a></li>
    <li><a href="">About|</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Schools|</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Submit Notes|</a></li>      
</ul>
```

Comment: Please mark this post as answered if I was able to answer your question.